# How to write a vb.net code to compile and execute C programs?

Tags: c, vb.net

I'm trying to make a vb.net application that has got 2 textboxes, 2 radio buttons and 2 buttons(one named compile and the other 'run'). How can I load the content of a C/C++ file into the 1st textbox and on clicking the compile button, i should be able to show the errors or the C/C++ program in the 2nd textbox. On clicking Run, I should be able to show the output in the 2nd textbox. In short, I want to use the 2nd textbox as a terminal/console. The radio buttons are 4 selecting the language C or C++.

Comment: Do you want to write a compiler in Visual BASIC.NET? Or invoke a compiler and execute the resulting application?

Comment: I'm completely missing the point of this question. What specifically are you trying to achieve here? Are you just trying to get VB.NET to shell out to a C/C++ compiler? And if so, why (what will you be doing with the compiler's stdout)? Knowing more helps give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [article](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/7914) - good examples on calling external programs (which is what your c++ compiler would be unless you intend to write your own) from VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to? What are you trying to do. Do you just want to execute the commandline compilers from a VB.NET Application ?

If so have a look at the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` method which allows you to execute another application.

Comment: I think the person who asked for help is trying to run the existing compiler from his software. In that case Eoin Cambell has gave the solution. Use, System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

Answer (score 0):

I don't think writing a `C++` compiler in `VB.NET` is something an *absolute beginner* should be undertaking.  Writing a compiler is a very advanced field.